# Nested Schema in Mongoose with NestJS

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to parse a response from Google's API into Mongoose using Nestjs, but I can't understand what is the correct way to parse and create a Schema for nested json objects, can someone help?

This is my JSON response:

```
{
  "reviewId": "f1a0ec26-9aca-424f-8b05-cff6aa3d2337",
  "authorName": "Some User",
  "comments": [
    {
      "userComment": {
        "text": "\tAmazing!",
        "lastModified": {
          "seconds": "1659685904",
        },
        "starRating": 5,
        "reviewerLanguage": "en",
      }
    },
    {
      "developerComment": {
        "text": "Thank you.",
        "lastModified": {
          "seconds": "1659688852",
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my Scheme:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface Review extends mongoose.Document {
  authorName: string;
  reviewId: string;
  userComment: {
    text: string;
    lastModified: string;
    starRating: number;
    reviewerLanguage: string;
  };
}

export const ReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  authorName: { type: String, required: true },
  reviewId: { type: String, index: { unique: true }, required: true },
  userComment: {
    text: { type: String, required: false },
    lastModified: { type: String, required: false },
    starRating: { type: Number, required: false },
    reviewerLanguage: { type: String, required: false },
  },
});
```

Then I am trying to create the object when the JSON response returned from the server:

```
const newReview = new this.reviewModel({
  authorName: review.authorName || 'NO_NAME',
  reviewId: review.reviewId || 'NO_ID',
  userComment.lastModified: review.userComment[0].lastModified || '',
});
```

[image]

[image]

But I get an error in userComment.lastModified, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: can you share the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is quite wrong, as the objects given in Models are key:value you cannot do

> userComment.lastmodifird:"abc"

```
const newReview = new this.reviewModel({
   authorName: review.authorName || 'NO_NAME',
   reviewId: review.reviewId || 'NO_ID',
   userComment:{lastModified: review.userComment[0].lastModified || ''},
   });
```

Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Thank you, but now I am getting another error `text: review.userComment[0].text || '',` -> `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

Comment: share the object of review you are getting from Request

Comment: I've shared it on the question itself..

Comment: try getting the text in a const outside the schema first, and then pass it into the schema . I guess the error is thrown before the code reaches the OR '||' operator.  use console.log() to find what data exactly you are sending.

Comment: Ok, found the answer, the json response is `comments[0].userComment...` - thank you very much for your help!